# Serving static files with echo middleware and embed

Tags: go, static, go-echo

```
project folder
->templates
  ->t.tmpl
->examples
  ->html
    ->blocks
      ->...
    ->assets
      ->...
    ->index.html
```

im t.tmpl there is call to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./blocks/index.css">` which in turn calls to different static files in `examples/html/blocks/` and `examples/html/assets`

I am using echo with such setup:

```
   
   e.Static("/i/blocks", "examples/html/blocks")
   e.Static("/i/assets", "examples/html/assets")
   e.Static("/i/blocks/body/examples/html/assets", "examples/html/assets")
   e.Static("/i/blocks/logo/examples/html/assets", "examples/html/assets")

   v1 := s.e.Group("/i")

   v1.GET("/:page-id", s.handlePageDetails)
```

it works as intended, BUT

I would like to make it simpler and not hardcoded.

Was hoping to solve it like so:

```
    e.Use(middleware.StaticWithConfig(middleware.StaticConfig{
        Root:       "examples/html",
        Browse:     true,
        IgnoreBase: true,
     }))
```

It seems to work locally, but then it turned out that probably e.Static cached or something, because it stopped working after i restarted IDE during update.

So back to square 1.

At the end want something like this(if it is possible) to work:

```
e.Use(middleware.StaticWithConfig(middleware.StaticConfig{
        Root:       "examples/html",
        Browse:     true,
        IgnoreBase: true,
        Filesystem: http.FS(project.StaticFiles),
     }))
```

where in some file static.go in the root of the project i have

```
//go:embed examples/html
var StaticFiles embed.FS
```

Not using Echo is not an option.
If this can not be achieved through middleware.StaticWithConfig then other options are welcome as long as it doesn't look like what I have with bunch of e.Static for every path possibilities.

Also. The way it works. So there's a Get request to http://localhost:8080/i/:some-id - it calls on template, template calls on statics, those requests look like i/blocks and such, that is why i'm so specific with e.statics, to remove that /i/ part

Comment: Have you considered using absolute path in the HTML and static files? For example, use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/blocks/index.css">` instead?

Comment: it gives 404 for absolute path

Comment: Reconfigure the router accordingly. What I want to say is, most of the time, it is a bad practice to use relative path in HTML.

Comment: the only way it allowed me to get through with e.static() is by setting href="./examples/html/blocks/index.css" so that it can remove initial, but that is pretty much the same of what i have in initial question; what I have works - I just don't like the way it looks, cuz it's smth that might require changing code when something else changes; it is possible that templates and statics might be somewhere outside in the future, so that there would be no need to go inside the code all the time and the way I did it makes that impossible )

Comment: It seems that we are not talking about the same thing. I meant to set up a route like this: `e.Static("/static", "examples/html")`, then reference to the static resources like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/blocks/index.css">`. Have you considered this solution?

Comment: it will still call GET i/static so it would be e.Static("/i/static", "examples/html"), how is that different from what I have? also styles and all provided by frontend developers, I have no desire going over 100 files to correct links )

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/blocks/index.css">` makes the  request goes to `/static/blocks/index.css` not matter what the URL of the page is. It's ok for the `index.css` file to use relative path to reference images and other assets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253477/discussion-between-aleksey-stadnikov-and-zeke-lu).

Answer (score 0):

Guess this can be considered closed.
Had a long discussion with @Zeke Lu

With his help came to conclusion that frontend messed up big time. When it is fixed everything can be done with 1 line of code other then lots and lots of them as service grows.

Answer (score 0):

Update. So I decided to play around a bit more and...
Solution offered by @Zeke Lu solved it perfectly without changing frontend.

All I did is made path in tmp absolute.
Was `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./blocks/index.css">`
Made `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/blocks/index.css">`

And middleware gets it now as it supposed to.

This

```
   e.Use(middleware.StaticWithConfig(middleware.StaticConfig{
        Root:       "examples/html",
        Browse:     true,
        IgnoreBase: true,
     }))
```

resolves everything no problem without bunch of e.Static()

checked and double-checked with cache and all, locally and in docker; works perfectly

Thanks for the tip @Zeke Lu

Happy coding to all.

Comment: Update. Got to be careful, when using IgnoreBase. With my set-up it caused POST quaries to ignore handler. So could not add any more data for pages to check it with GET afterwards. My set up now: ```   e.Use(middleware.StaticWithConfig(middleware.StaticConfig{
        Root:       "examples/html",
        Browse:     true,
     })) ```